# code generate Azure Servicebus Namespace

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

I'm trying to figure out a way to create Azure Servicebus namespace using Azure manage API, cmdlets or REST API, so that I can create repeatable scripts for my deployment. Right now the only way I know how to create the Servicebus Namespace is through the Azure Portal.

**Is there a scriptable (c#, powershell) way to create a new azure servicebus w/o using the Azure portal**?

here's a few links I've already read through:

Azure Cmdlets: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152841.aspx

API References for Windows Azure: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff800682.aspx

[Declaritively and Programitcally Subscribing to the Windows Azure Service Bus Relay with WCF](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/18/declaritively-and-programitcally-subscribing-to-the-windows-azure-service-bus-relay-with-wcf/)

[How to Use the Service Bus Relay Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/)

Thank you in advance.

Gasshope

Comment: The service bus root namespace create should be viewed similarly to the cloud service namespace. So the first question I'd have is why you need to programmatically create them? Is this because you're created a deployment package to be used by folks who are leveraging your solution and you're just trying to streamline the install for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Not sure if it is in the works, but as of right now you can only create a namespace in the portal.

Comment: Please comment on a post you down-vote to discuss the issue you have with the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the latest version of the [Azure SDK tools](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/tree/dev) to create namespaces via powershell. [This blog post](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/12/14/new-windows-azure-powershell-update-december-2012/) has a good tutorial on how to use the SDK, and which ServiceBus operations are available.

Answer (score 0):

The [Create Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj856303.aspx) in the Windows Azure Service Bus REST API can be used for that.

According to the documentation:

> Creates a new service namespace. Once created, this namespace’s resource manifest is immutable. This operation is idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

"You can use PowerShell to create Service Bus resources, to get started you must have general understanding of PowerShell scripts, NuGet packages, and the .NET Framework. Read this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-manage-with-ps) for more information."

Comment: While it is nice to know that this is possible, does this really answer the question?