# Create Azure ServiceBus Namaspace

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-management-api

Is it possible to programmatically create a ServiceBus namspace, create identities, assign Send/Listen permissions, etc?

I found the [following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923003/code-generate-azure-servicebus-namespace) from two years ago but I suspect things have changed in the mean time and the answer might be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can create it using the Azure PowerShell cmdlets (for example, in East US):

```
New-AzureSBNamespace -Name "[YOUR SB NAMESPACE NAME]" -Location "East US"
```

There is always the REST API.  I've not used it for Service Bus or I would give you a sample.  Instead, here is the link to it for your reference. :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj856303.aspx

There is also a client library (in preview) that you can use if you want the C# experience.

[image]

Here is sample code using the Service Bus Management Library:

```
        // Get this from the portal
        var subscriptionId = "5f830156-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
        // Get this from your .publishsettings file
        var managementCert = "MIIKFAI...really long string of base64...==";

        var creds = new CertificateCloudCredentials(
            subscriptionId,
            new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(managementCert)));

        ServiceBusManagementClient sbMgmtClient = new ServiceBusManagementClient(creds);
        sbMgmtClient.Namespaces.Create("[YOUR SB NAMESPACE NAME]", "East US");
```

Comment: These two suggestions where mentioned in the answers to SO question I linked to. I was hoping there was something I could use directly in my C# code without hand coding REST calls.

Comment: Apparently there is also a management library (in preview).  I just updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't know about this library, I will have a look.

Comment: I was able to create a Namespace in only a few minutes with the library you suggested. Excellent. Now I need to figure out how to configure the Rule Groups and the Identities...